# How to bind image visibility to user property

Tags: image, binding, xamarin.forms, visibility, xamarin-studio

I am working on Xamarin Forms using Xamarin Studio.
I am getting problem to bind image visibility as below. Please suggest me some changes. Thanks in advance.

```
var radiobtn_preference = new CircleImage {
            BorderColor = ColorResources.commonButtonBackgroundColor,
            HeightRequest = 25,
            WidthRequest = 25,
            Aspect = Aspect.AspectFill,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            Source="radio_uncheck.png",
        };
```

radiobtn_preference.SetBinding (radiobtn_preference.IsVisible, "isExcluded");

public class table
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string id{ get; set;}
        public bool isExcluded{ get; set;}
    }

```
public static class tableData
{

    public static List<table> GetData ()
    {

        return new List<table> {
            new table () {
                Name="Peru",isExcluded=true,
            },
            new table () {
                Name="Apple",isExcluded=false,
            },
            new table () {
                Name="Grapes",isExcluded=true,
            },
        };
    }

}
```

I declare image and trying to bind its visibility to property set by user.

Comment: And what is the trouble you have with this? What have you tried? Where did you fail?

Comment: Error : The best overloaded method match for `Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetBinding(Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty, Xamarin.Forms.BindingBase)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert `bool' expression to type `Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty'

Comment: Ah yes, try this; radiobtn_preference.SetBinding (CircleImage.IsVisibleProperty, "isExcluded");

Comment: Great @GeraldVersluis. Thanks. You solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As deduced from the comments there is an error in your code:

`radiobtn_preference.SetBinding (radiobtn_preference.IsVisible, "isExcluded");`

Should be

`radiobtn_preference.SetBinding (CircleImage.IsVisibleProperty, "isExcluded");`

Notice how the first parameter has changed. This parameter should be the identifier of the property you are binding to, not the actual instantiated property.
If it was to be bound to a `Grid` note that you'd have to use `Grid.IsVisibleProperty`. Or if you wanted to bind another property like the `IsEnabled` property you would have to use the `CircleImage.IsEnabledProperty` identifier.